# Wordpress loop with different bootstrap columns

Tags: php, loops, wordpress-theming

i need to create a wordpress loop where the first post will be col-md-12 and the next 4 posts will be col-md-6

```
<div class= "col-md-12">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
```

and then

```
<div class= "col-md-12">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
<div class= "col-md-6">
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And do you want the list twice?

Comment: no i want it to repeat itself every time starts with md-12 and the next 4 posts md-6

Comment: You can use `%5` (modulo operator)

Comment: the html you add , you have to create one column with 12 and 2 lines with 6 (4 columns of 6 ) is that right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this can help :

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
     $counter = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) {

    if(($counter%5) == 0 ){?>
        <div class= "col-md-12"> call the loop tags of the curent post to show data that you want </div>
<?php
}
    else{?>

     <div class= "col-md-6"> call the loop tags of the curent post to show data that you want </div>

    <?php }

    $counter++;
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

In case to limit post to 10 post only:

```
   <?php 
    $wp =  new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>10));
    if ( $wp->have_posts() ) {
         $counter = 0;
        while ( $wp->have_posts() ) {

        if(($counter%5) == 0 ){?>
            <div class= "col-md-12"> call the loop tags of the curent post to show data that you want </div>
    <?php
    }
        else{?>

         <div class= "col-md-6"> call the loop tags of the curent post to show data that you want </div>

        <?php }

        $counter++;
        } // end while
    } // end if
    ?>
```

> you have to call all the tags like : the_title(), the_content()
>   preceded by $wp , **but not obligation**

Comment: it keeps getting the posts with col-md-12

Comment: sorry i have to initial counter before while

Comment: perfect it works but the loop never stops it keeps getting posts from the database

i need to get only 10 posts

Comment: break the loop if the counter reach 10

Comment: But then you're still grabbing unneccessary data from the database, better to limit the number of posts in the query with the `posts_per_page` argument

Comment: Try adding query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' ); immediately before the <?php while (have_posts()) ?> , does it work ?

Comment: $counter = 0;
        query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' );
       while ( have_posts() ) {

Comment: it's not working it keeps getting data without stooping

Comment: `if ( have_posts() ) {
        $counter = 0;
        query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' );
       while ( have_posts() ) {

       if(($counter%5) == 0 ){?>`

Comment: in that case  , you need to create a new query like:
$wp = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>10)); ?>

Comment: Thanks @MohammedYassineCHABLI I really appreciate your help

Comment: with pleasure ,check now

Comment: still the same its not stopping i tried the default wodpress loop  its gets only 3  

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
and ends here:

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
 <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: yes i check it 
but sadly its not working its keep getting posts without stopping

Comment: Let me explain more if this is for the main loop in the index.php page and i need it to work with the main wordpress pagination so if i changed the settings in the reading section in the admin area so it shows only the last 10

Comment: i found the  solution you need to include the_post(); after  while ( have_posts() ) {

Thanks @MohammedYassineCHABLI

Comment: sorry , i forget to mention that . enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try a ternary operator:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    $counter = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) {    
        $colClass = ($counter%5) == 0 ) ? "col-md-12" : "col-md-6";
        echo '<div class= "' . $colClass . '">';
        // Post data
        echo '</div>';   
        $counter++;
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```